# multipart/form-data API POST call with X509 Client Certificate

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to make a multipart/form-data API POST call to upload a file. The call must be authenticated with an X509 Client Certificate. Preferably I'd like to use Windows PowerShell to do this so I can access the X509 Store in windows without decrypting the PKI. I have found examples of doing this with basic authorizations but have not found anything that explains doing this with PKIs.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you want an example of how client certificate is used in Invoke-WebRequest? On a high level, it's as easy as 1) getting certificate from the user store:

```
$certs = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My
```

and then using the certificate in iwr ot irm:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://stackoverflow.com" -Certificate $cert[0]
```

Ref.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6

Andd here's Mark Kraus's blog post on how to use multipart/form-data: https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com.au/2017/09/multipartform-data-support-for-invoke.html

Note: use PowerShell Core 6, this is new feature.